# How do I install Flash in the guest account only?

Tags: macos, adobe-flash

Is there a way to install Adobe Flash to the Guest account (only)?  I'd like to install to the Guest account so it gets wiped out on reboot.  I rarely use Flash, so I want to not have to track updates.

Either that, can I install it to a non-Admin account that I can wipe out when I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Google Chrome has a sandboxed built-in version of Flash.

1. Download Chrome.
2. Navigate to: Macintosh HD> Users> Guests
3. Right Click and select "New Folder" and change its name to Applications
4. Open the Google Chrome disk image and drag Chrome.app to this folder

Google Chrome and its Flash player will only be accessible to the Guest user.

Answer (score -1):

Mabe this will do the trick ? 
First of all you may need to unhide the hiden files so open terminal and run those commands :

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

killall Finder
```

To switch back, do the same but substitute FALSE for TRUE.

Now 
Login to your guest account, there set chrome as your default browser (or even Firefox) 
Then do not logout ! This would erase your session, so use the  on the top right corner use the swich user drop down menue, 
Now that you are back again in your Admin account,
Find the new temporary guest home folder, under

```
 Users/Guest
```

Select all the folders inside of it,
And copy them in :

```
 /System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/
```

English or whatever your languish is if you are using your computer in french this should be :

```
  /System/Library/User Template/French.lproj/
```

as you can see in this folder there was the defaults folders for the guest account 
By modifying them you have just modified default appearance of the guest user account
You may want to save this folder in a safe place before, in case you want to undo your work.

For reference , 
You just have to follow the steps as shown in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU-W2-_c5bA

Or if you prefer text version :

http://www.michaelsmac.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=394

Comment: Please refrain from fluff like "Hope this helped ! I worked fine for me ! And it's realy easy and safe If you do the backup as described in the video !

Don't forget to vote up !" Try to provide good answers and no fluff for the best chance to get votes that are positive.